# Horror movie in the jungle with ants, centipedes and a big snake

Tags: identify-this-movie

I had watched a kind of horror movie in round about 2008 but I don't know the release date of the movie itself.

In that movie a group of people went on journey to jungle and soon some strange events start happening with them and one by one they got killed by jungle creatures(ants, scorpions, centipedes, snake etc). In one event a person got eaten by large colony of ants, later one person got eaten by scorpions or centipedes or so, later in the journey some got slipped and had similar fortune.
I could saw centipedes or something flowing inside the skin of the person being attacked. I remember that at the end about 2-3 persons left and they had to face a BIG snake in the river. Some how they killed the snake and went out of the jungle to some other town through a boat which they had made from some woods. Those 2-3 were the only persons who survived.

It was a color English movie(I am confused if it was English but i think so, I was young I hardly cared to listen to them I was fully immersed in the scene). In the journey through lush green jungle they passed through valleys. Climbed steep paths etc. The whole movie was full of unfortunate events. Almost complete movie was made in jungle, only the last few minutes of movie showed a town where the survived persons had reached through small boat like structure.

I don't exactly remember neither the names of the actors nor anything else that can give me a keyword to search in google to find.

Comment: Welcome to Movies & TV! We have a minimum standard for ID questions. Please try to add anything that may help identification. When was it released? Was it in Color or Black & White? What time period was it showing? What country was it likely from or what language was it in? Are there any other plot details you remember? Descriptions of scenes or names of characters or actors you can give? Feel free to [edit] any additional details into the question. **You might also want to provide a more descriptive question title**

Comment: It sounds familiar to me. I think I may have watched it (or at least part of it, on TV). Where you are talking of the "creatures" - are you talking about natives but with a really sadistic and depraved twist, who take pleasure in completely gratuitously killing some of the travelers in very cruel ways? If so, it's one more element of the plot which can help you identifying the movie.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds like  [The Trek](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0495589/combined) from 2002. It's Thai, though (but there are a few non-Thai actors).

> Reports about the discovery of a unique Asian elephant prompts the Kochaban Club, an elephant protection group, and a team of foreign researchers to search for the beast in the wild. But the jungle it inhabits is host to a various dangers, from menacing drug smugglers to an array of deadly jungle creatures. No explorer has ever returned from the particular wilderness that the route encompasses and the group can't find a local tribesman who's prepared to guide them. They proceed nonetheless, and soon begin to find out why even the natives are terrified to enter the jungle - as a whole host of dangers closes in for the kill.

They're all killed one by one by killer centipedes, ants, scorpions etc. It ends like you described: three survive, confront a giant snake and reach the local village. Here's a 10 minute video with some of the prominent scenes, including centipedes borrowing under the skin **[Warning: Gory]**: